# Jquery TextArea add class on change event and disable others elements on submit

Tags: jquery, class

I am trying to add a class to textarea on keyup event . The event is firing but the class is not getting added . Here I am trying to add the class if it doesn't exist to that textarea instance

```
  $("textarea").live("keyup", function() {
    $("this[class='']").addClass("modified");
      });
```

During submit , I am using the below code to disable the ones which doesn't have class modified . But this is not submitting any textareas . So looks like no class is being added in the above code .

```
$("textarea:not(.modified)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Could some one help me what the problem with this code?

Thanks

Regards

Kiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
$("textarea").live("keyup", function(e) {
  $(e.target).addClass("modified");
});
```

The class will not be added if it is present already.

Comment: This is more elegant than my solution.

Comment: Thank You Riateche for your help . I don't know in the first place why I added class='' . Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities:

When using the keyword `this` in jQuery, you do not need quotation marks.

I'd try something like:

```
if ( !($(this.hasClass("modified")) ){

     $(this).addClass("modified");
}
```

The second issue might be that you are trying to add a class to an object with no classes, is it possible there already is another class on that field?

Comment: I would actually use Raiteche's solution over mine as it is much more straightforward and jQuery will make sure not to add the duplicate anyway. I think the main issue with your code is the use of the 'this' keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Kiran,

I tested this and it does add the class on keyup. Try this instead of your code to see if it works.

```
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
    $(this).addClass("modified");
  });
```

What's you're form onsubmit look like? Have you tired to throw a debugger in the code to see if your `$("textarea:not(.modified)").attr("disabled", "disabled");` is getting hit at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
  $("textarea").on("keyup", function() {
       $(this).addClass("modified");
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Thulasiram for this solution